# Testing with Rspec get errors , But testing with brower works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Hello friends I have something to confess first,my previous account was banned from asking questions,From now on, i will try to make the questions more clear and precise!

I'm working on Hartl's ruby on rails tutorials ,i have been stuck at `chapter 9.2.2 Requiring the right user`    `"Listing 9.13 Testing that the edit and update actions require the right user" for a few days. I have done lots of  research,i went back and forth of the chapters , it didn't work and it seems no one had the issue that i have now . Let me explain in details.

Errors:

```
Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
     TypeError:
       wrong argument type nil (expected Regexp)
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.77 seconds
64 examples, 1 failure
```

i have tested with the brower,it works perfectly,i tried to edit other users. the page was directed to the home page successfully!

Github: https://github.com/Snailseason2014/Sample

here are some related files:

spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
    require 'spec_helper'
describe 'Authentication' do
  subject { page }
  describe 'signin page' do
    before { visit signin_path }
    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end
  describe 'signin' do
    before { visit signin_path }
    describe 'with invalid information' do
      before { click_button 'Sign in' }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe 'after visiting another page' do
        before { click_link 'Home' }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alter-error') }
      end
    end
    describe 'with valid information' do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe 'followed by signout' do
        before { click_link 'Sign out' }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end
  describe 'authorization' do
    describe 'for non-signed-in users' do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe 'in the Users controller' do

        describe 'visiting the edit page' do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end
        describe 'submitting to the update action' do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end
    describe 'as wrong user' do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: 'wrong@example.com') }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe 'submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action' do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe 'submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action' do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = 'welcome'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Profile updated'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
  # Before filters

  def signed_in_user
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: 'Please sign in.' unless signed_in?
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of Hartl's tutorial are you have ? There's no chapter 9.13 on my copy or even on [his webpage](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users)

Comment: Hi Pawel, I have this version of Hartl's tutorial . Thank u very much for replying me , I have seen the hope !  its at 9.2.2 Requiring the right user Requiring signed-in users https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users

Comment: it was at chapter 9.2.2 Listing 9.13, I just modified the question , Thank u

Comment: Looks like the github repo is not up-to-date.

Comment: Thank u pawel7318 , i have skipped rspec, i decided to figure it out later. Thank u very much for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you skipped some of the exercises, specifically the exercises in section 5.6, which would have prevented your error.

In any case, in chapter 5 the tutorial had you define a duplicate full_title() helper for the tests to use, which was to be put in the file:

```
spec/support/utilities.rb
```

The original full_title() helper was used by the views.

Looking at your `spec/support/utilities.rb` file, you have this:

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
```

Can you see what's wrong?  It's obvious that you copy and pasted that code from the text of the tutorial, and you missed the last line which was: `end`, which is required to close the def you started on the first line. However, I cannot explain why you haven't been getting a SyntaxError when trying to run your tests, which prevents the tests from running at all when I try it.

Comment: Thank u so much, it makes A Whole Lot Of Sense now! I will definitely go back and do the test again, But i have been skipping  the test since then, now i almost finished the whole book, after that i will read an independent  book about "Rspec" , Thank u again 7stud! You just put me on the right track. :) i represent 1.4 billion Chinese people to wish you the best!

Comment: I figured out why you are not getting a SyntaxError for the missing end. Your last method definition in spec/support/utilities.rb has an extra `end`, which looks like it's part of the last def because the indenting for your last method is completely screwed up. If you use a computer programming text editor with automatic indenting, then you should realize when you have an error like a missing end, because when you type the next line, the indenting will not be to the correct level. That is a warning that you need to look at the previous lines and figure out what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your spec:

```
expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user'))
```

a `match` exepctation is expected to match some text against a regular expression eg:

```
expect("hello").to match(/ell/)   # => true
expect("hello").to match(/blah/)  # => false
```

`full_title('Edit user')` is not a regular expression... it's some content on the page. So it really isn't the right thing to use in an `expect...match`. You can turn any string into a regular expression by putting it inside // and using string-interpolation syntax eg:

```
a_string = 'some string'
a_regex = /#{a_string}/
```

so here you could use:

```
expect(response.body).not_to match(/#{full_title('Edit user')}/)
```

HOWEVER... the error message you get is indicative of something deeper... it says that you are passing a nil instead of a regular expression... which means that `full_title('Edit user')` is evaluating to nil instead of an actual string.

if you use my example above... the spec will likely still fail... so you have to figure out why `full-title('Edit user')` is returning nil and fix that first.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question ! I really appreciate ! I had been stuck with this error for almost 10 days , after that I decided to  move on , I'm at the end of chapter 10 now , I have been skipping the rspec test since  then, after I finish reading the tutorial , I will go back and read a book about rspec , I'm not sure if I'm doing right, but your answer helps me understand rspec more! Thank u so much!

Comment: **full_title('Edit user') is not a regular expression... it's some content on the page. So it really isn't the right thing to use in an expect...match** Although, I can find no documentation for this (or anything on google), match() does take a String argument, which is what the ROR Tut uses for the arguments to match().

Comment: ok... but match likely blows up if you pass it a nil.... and `full_title('Edit user')` is clearly evaluating to nil (because that's what the error message says)

Comment: Im sorry guys, I just found that i can't accept  two answers simultaneously, As 7stud mentioned, i did skip some exercises. i think that was my issue. On the other hand Taryn did help me understand more about Rspec .But i really appreciate both answers. I wish i had enough credits vote up both answers. Thank u both.

Comment: you can upvote both answers... (click the little up-traingle). you just can't "accept" both answers (slight nuance in what they mean).

Comment: Unfortunately ,  Vote-up requires 15 reputations , I'm sorry i have 3 only, I will vote up until i have 15 reputations. :) I promise u Taryn!

Comment: **Although, I can find no documentation for this** The rspec match() method just calls match() on the subject, which in this case is response.body, which is a String; and String#match() takes a String or a Regexp as an argument, and String#match() automatically converts a String argument to a Regexp.

Comment: Thank u so much for the effort on this 7stud !